# How to return the original state after a search filter function has been cleared in redux store redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a search and filter function which I want to implement whereby a user will search for items and they will be returned in a flatlist and when the user clears the search box or the search box is empty I want the initial state to be returned.

I've tried this:
The function does filter through the store but when I clear it, the original state items are no longer there. What is returned are the search values

```
    search: (state, { payload }) => {
      const itemsToFilter = state.filter((item) => {
        let itemLowerCase = item.item_description.toLowerCase();

        let searchItemToLowerCase = payload.item_description.toLowerCase();

        return itemLowerCase.indexOf(searchItemToLowerCase) > -1;
      });

      if (payload.item_description.length !== 0) {
        return itemsToFilter;
      } else {
        return state;
      }
    },
```

Here is my component function

```
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';

  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  
  const items = useSelector(state => state.items)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const searchItems = (e) => {
    const text = e.nativeEvent.text;
    setSearchValue(text);

    dispatch(
      searchItemAction({
        item_description: searchValue,
      })
    );
  };

<TextInput value={searchValue} onChange={searchItems} />
```

Comment: What is the  "orginal state items" supposed to be? If you need to retain an original set of items, best to save them as static data and call it on some action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, `useState()` is async so your dispatch is using the old string.

```
  const searchItems = (e) => {
    const text = e.nativeEvent.text;
    setSearchValue(text); // Will be updated async

    dispatch(
      searchItemAction({
        item_description: searchValue, //searchValue will still be the old search value
      })
    );
  };
```

easy solution would be to use the `text` variable:

```
  const searchItems = (e) => {
    const text = e.nativeEvent.text;
    setSearchValue(text);

    dispatch(
      searchItemAction({
        item_description: text,
      })
    );
  };
```

also, where do you store your orignal data? you should create a selector instead and it would be fine.

i think the best solution would be to use the selector only in this component (if you don't need it anywhere else):

```
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

const items = useSelector(state => {
  if(searchValue.length === 0) {
    return state.items;
  }
  return state.items.filter((item) => {
    let itemLowerCase = item.item_description.toLowerCase();
    let searchItemToLowerCase = searchValue.toLowerCase();
    return itemLowerCase.indexOf(searchItemToLowerCase) > -1;
  });
}

const searchItems = (e) => {
  const text = e.nativeEvent.text;
  setSearchValue(text);
};
```

otherwise you will need to store the search string to redux and use the stored string to do the filter in the selector.

Comment: If I knew who you are... I would buy you one of the finest scotch whiskey, I've been at for the past 6days. your solution worked and it was quite simple. I've tried using ```useSelector``` to search and filter guess I was implementing it in a wrong way. Thank you so much.